# OpenLayers 2.12 Release Schedule?

Tags: openlayers-2, open-source-gis

Does anyone here know when OpenLayers 2.12 is likely to become a Stable release rather than a release candidate, it contains so many handy performance and user interface improvements that I really want to get it into our application but me and my colleagues are (only slightly) hesistant about using a release candidate and would rather use a stable release.

If its going to be ages or unknown then I'll probably just use the release candidate I am using for developement (I think its rc-8) as it seems perfectly stable, just wondered if the community had any idea!

Thanks!

Comment: If it is perfectly stable, why not just use it? At rc-8, I cannot think it has anything big that needs fixing...

Comment: In addition to Ragi Yaser Burhum's comment, I would add, there only appears to be one ticket open which relates to URL handling with Internet Explorer 10 (which is only in public beta). [Open Layers development tickets...](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/query?status=assigned&status=new&status=reopened&group=status&milestone=2.12+Release)

Comment: @RagiYaserBurhum I thought the same to be honest, but others were a bit hesistant, and since we are in a Local Governement environment we'll likely get our heads bitten off if it fails!

Comment: @DMan Nice spot, I'd been following the OpenLayers project on GitHub but didn't realise they had trac as well, that'll be handy! Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Final 2.12 release was announced today.

http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/Release/2.12/Announce/Final

Comment: Btw, I'm just a (very) active user and monitor the timeline (http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/timeline) for updates frequently.  I'm not associated with the core OL team.

Comment: Nice spot, I'll be bookmarking that for the future. Cheers!